# R: ddply only returns first column of matrix column

Tags: r, matrix, plyr

I have a data.frame `D` where some columns are matrices, e.g.

```
> head(round(D$equationRTs, 1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]  2.9  2.1  3.2  3.5   NA   NA   NA
[2,]  2.8   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]  3.4  2.4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[4,]  2.7  2.9  1.9   NA   NA   NA   NA
[5,]  3.6  2.6  2.4  2.4  3.4  2.8   NA
[6,]  2.4  2.0  3.3  2.8  2.8  2.6  3.6
...

> dim(D$equationRTs)
[1] 11277     7

> typeof(D$equationRTs)
[1] "double"
```

However, when I do a `ddply` to subset `D`:

```
my_function = function(df) {
    # Let's see what ddply passes to this function:
    print(head(round(df$equationRTs, 1)))
    print(dim(df$equationRTs))
    print(typeof(df$equationRTs))
}

D = ddply(D, .(id), my_function)
```

it appears that only the first column is passed to `my_function` as vector:

```
[1] 2.9 2.8 3.4 2.7 3.6 2.4
NULL
[1] "double"
```

Column 2-6 are just gone. What's going on here and how do I make the matrix column stay intact when subsets are passed to `my_function`?

Bonus: it seems that ddply is doing something like `D$equationRTs[id==x]` which indeed returns the first column of the matrix whereas `D$equationRTs[id==x, ]` returns the matrix.

Comment: Can you show a small reproducible data and your `myfunction` so that we don't have to guess what might be the problem

Comment: I've updated the question to show data and ``my_function``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply manually code what `ddply` does (or should do...).

So replace the old

```r
D = ddply(D, .(id), my_function)
```

with

```r
for(id in levels(D$id)) {
    D[D$id == id, ] = check_quality(D[D$id == id, ])
}
```

The manual version has the desired behavior.